# Using Aurelia, how to use route-href to reference child routes?

Tags: routes, aurelia

Using Aurelia, how does one use `route-href` to construct an anchor tag href that references child routes?

In app.js, define a route to a parent view.

```
config.map([
{ 
   route: 'parentview,
   name: 'parentview',
   moduleId: './parentview'
}]);
```

In parentview.js, configure routes to child views:

```
config.map([
{ 
   route: ['', 'childviewone'], name: 'childviewone', moduleId: './childviewone' },
   route:      'childviewtwo',  name: 'childviewtwo', moduleId: './childviewtwo' }
]);
```

I have found no way to use `route-href` to construct an anchor tag href that looks like "parentview/childviewone" or "parentview/childviewtwo".

This seems like a simple and potentially common scenario.  Perhaps the following issues are getting in the way?  Or am I missing something?

https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/89

https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/90

Comment: How are you trying to use `route-href` currently?

Comment: @thebluefox  Do you have an idea that might work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think `aurelia-router` currently support generating URLs to child routers from the parent router. Router configurations are currently lazy loaded, so the routes for the child routes is unknown until the component with the route configuration is displayed. You can generate routes to parent routes, or routes in the same scope, but not from another child route or root route to a sub route.